# Strange scenario getting g++ error multiple definition of functions

Tags: c++, hyperlink, g++, definition

I have code that already works but need to port it to yet another Linux platform.  I'm always having to tune the code for gcc/g++ differences - usually the given version of g++ is just more limited in what it allows.

In this case, I am getting a multiple function definition error in a very simple case - a single global function in a single cpp file being called once. I do not see any duplicate listing of the object file in the final g++ link line. There are no duplicates either in the source file text (by searching), or in the compiled object file (using objdump -t).  In fact, the error confirms there is no true duplicate by listing the same offset in the object:

ACTUAL LINK ERROR:
Simulation1.o: In function `DoSimulation1(int, char**)':
Simulation1.cpp:(.text+0x1800): multiple definition of`DoSimulation1(int, char**)'
Simulation1.o:Simulation1.cpp:(.text+0x1800): first defined here

Note two odd things - (1) both original and duplicate are at .text+0x1800, and (2) it seems to be finding a duplicate of the function being called inside the function, but this is not a recursive function and it does not call itself.

Here's the link line:

> g++ -O3 -std=c++11 CorrelatePCandFrequency.o CountBroadcasts.o
>   CheckMemDependencies.o MathModel.o Histograms2.o EvalOddSetCaches2.o
>   jDEQ.o ChipControl.o jSimplestCache.o WorkingSets.o
>   EvalOddSetCaches3.o QuickAnal.o Simulation1.o copy.o
>   ValidateTrailFile.o jCommon.o CountBroadcasts2.o jSimpleCache2.o
>   BankConflicts.o ParsePTXTrace.o DynamicTrace.o copy.o Simulation1.o
>   Histograms.o jExcel.o main.o jPreConditionedHintFile.o JVector.o
>   jBitArray.o Ops.o -o sim

The single function definition in the file Simulation1.cpp:

```
bool DoSimulation1(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
  ...
  }
```

Note that when I do objdump -t on Simulation1.o and then c++filt, I get a slight variation:

0000000000001800 g     F .text  000000000000049b _Z13DoSimulation1iPPc

c++filt _Z13DoSimulation1iPPc
DoSimulation1(int, char**)

So if there's anything a miss it could be the difference between char** and char* [])

Again, this compiles fine on other platforms.
This error is with:
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC)

Any thoughts?  Normally errors like this are from putting a definition in an include file, or having weird template overloading effects.  This is quite simple, and it won't link the executable as a result.

Thanks
- Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have two `Simulation1.o` in your link command?

> g++ -O3 -std=c++11 CorrelatePCandFrequency.o CountBroadcasts.o
>   CheckMemDependencies.o MathModel.o Histograms2.o EvalOddSetCaches2.o
>   jDEQ.o ChipControl.o jSimplestCache.o WorkingSets.o
>   EvalOddSetCaches3.o QuickAnal.o **Simulation1.o** copy.o
>   ValidateTrailFile.o jCommon.o CountBroadcasts2.o jSimpleCache2.o
>   BankConflicts.o ParsePTXTrace.o DynamicTrace.o copy.o **Simulation1.o**
>   Histograms.o jExcel.o main.o jPreConditionedHintFile.o JVector.o
>   jBitArray.o Ops.o -o sim

(copy.o seems to be duplicated too)